# React select box function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make a custom select box component with parent and shild components, with autocomplete and also fetching from api. The problem is that i am trying to fire `onchange` function from parent to child to select an item from the select box but it is not working, can someone tell me where is the problem?

```
export function SelectComponent() {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState<ComboBoxOption>();

  const handleOnChange = (e: any) => {
    if (!e.target.value.trim()) return setResults([]);

    const filteredValue = results.filter((item: any) =>
      item.value.toString().toLowerCase().startsWith(item.toLowerCase())
    );
    setResults(filteredValue);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(...);
setResults(response.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <SelectField
        options={results}
        value={selectedValue?.value}
        onChange={handleOnChange}
        onSelect={item => setSelectedValue(item)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export function SelectField({
...
}: SelectFieldProps) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const [defaultValue, setDefaultValue] = useState("");

  const handleOnChange: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = event => {
    setIsOpen(true);
    setDefaultValue(event.target.value);
    onChange && onChange(event);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={defaultValue}
        onChange={handleOnChange}
      />
      <button onClick={() => {setIsOpen(!isOpen);}}></button>
          <ul>
            {options.map((option: any, index: any) => {
              return (
                <li
                  key={index}
                  onClick={() => {setIsOpen(false);}
                >
                  <span>{option.value}</span>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        )
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem may be in the `handleOnChange` function in the `SelectComponent`. The function is trying to filter the `results` state based on the `value` of the input element, but it should be filtering based on the `e.target.value` instead. Also, it's using `item.toLowerCase()` which doesn't make sense, instead it should use `e.target.value.toLowerCase()`:

```
const handleOnChange = (e: any) => {
    if (!e.target.value.trim()) return setResults([]);

    const filteredValue = results.filter((item: any) =>
      item.value.toString().toLowerCase().startsWith(e.target.value.toLowerCase())
    );
    setResults(filteredValue);
};
```

Also, in the `SelectField` component, it seems that you are not calling the `onSelect` prop when an option is selected. You should call the `onSelect` prop and pass the selected option as a parameter when an option is clicked, like so:

```
<li
  key={index}
  onClick={() => {
    setIsOpen(false);
    onSelect(option);
  }}
>
  <span>{option.value}</span>
</li>
```

I would also recommend using `onBlur` instead of `onClick` for the input field, this way it can be closed when the user clicks outside of the component.